# Adding filtering support to Xuggler

Tags: java, filter, xuggle

I need to have ability to filter video in Java. Xuggle (FFMpeg wrapper for Java) can decode and encode video, but unfortunately can not filter it.

I found this patches to Xuggle: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/xuggler-users/Dl1sMnCZvLw/m4h6FNzYTXUJ

1. They do not match to current version of Xuggle. And they not contain version info. I manually tried to fix this issue.
2. After installing SWIG 2.0 fnd compiling Xuggle in maintenance mode under ubuntu 11.10
   I have this error:

   `enter code here[exec] ./xuggler/.libs/libxuggle-xuggler.a(Xuggler.o):Xuggler.cpp:(.text+0x60f1a): undefined reference to`com::xuggle::xuggler::IFilterGraph::make(char const*, int, int, com::xuggle::xuggler::IPixelFormat::Type, com::xuggle::xuggler::IPixelFormat::Type, com::xuggle::xuggler::IRational*, com::xuggle::xuggler::IRational*)'
    [exec] ./xuggler/.libs/libxuggle-xuggler.a(Xuggler.o):Xuggler.cpp:(.text+0x61340): undefined reference to `com::xuggle::xuggler::IFilterGraph::make(char const*, int, int, com::xuggle::xuggler::IPixelFormat::Type)'
    [exec] collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    [exec] make[4]: *** [libxuggle.la] Error 1`

Could anybody share experience in building Xuggle with adding native code, generating Java wrappers by SWIG?  The goal is exporting ffmpeg filters to Java. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG 1.3.40 is what i needed. SWIG 2.0 is not compatible with Xuggle build system.